# Extract row/column indices in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of a plate map from an ELISA I did.  I'm trying to extract the exact indices of where the standards (STD) are using which(), but I constantly get only the column indices. I thought that the [1] may be indicating the first row, but when I repeat to find the sample indices (SPL), only the columns are still outputted. What am I doing wrong?

```
plate.map <- structure(list(`1` = c("BLK", "SPL1", "SPL2", "SPL3", "SPL4", 
"SPL5", "SPL6", "SPL7"), `2` = c("BLK", "SPL8", "SPL9", "SPL10", 
"SPL11", "SPL12", "SPL13", "SPL14"), `3` = c("STD1", "SPL15", 
"SPL16", "SPL17", "SPL18", "SPL19", "SPL20", "SPL21"), `4` = c("STD2", 
"SPL22", "SPL23", "SPL24", "SPL25", "SPL26", "SPL27", "SPL28"
), `5` = c("STD3", "SPL29", "SPL30", "SPL31", "SPL32", "SPL33", 
"SPL34", "SPL35"), `6` = c("STD4", "SPL36", "SPL37", "SPL38", 
"SPL39", "SPL40", "SPL41", "SPL42"), `7` = c("STD5", "SPL43", 
"SPL44", "SPL45", "SPL46", "SPL47", "SPL48", "SPL49"), `8` = c("STD6", 
"SPL50", "SPL51", "SPL52", "SPL53", "SPL54", "SPL55", "SPL56"
), `9` = c("STD7", "SPL57", "SPL58", "SPL59", "SPL60", "SPL61", 
"SPL62", "SPL63"), `10` = c("STD8", "SPL64", "SPL65", "SPL66", 
"SPL67", "SPL68", "SPL69", "SPL70"), `11` = c("PosCtrl", "SPL71", 
"SPL72", "SPL73", "SPL74", "SPL75", "SPL76", "SPL77"), `12` = c("PosCtrl", 
"SPL78", "SPL79", "SPL80", "SPL81", "SPL82", "SPL83", "SPL84"
)), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "data.frame")

which(grepl("STD", plate.map), arr.ind = TRUE)
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

which(grepl("SPL", plate.map), arr.ind = TRUE)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grepl` works only for vectors. Use `apply`:

```
which(apply(plate.map, 2, grepl, pattern="STD"), arr.ind = TRUE)
#  row col
#A   1   3
#A   1   4
#A   1   5
#A   1   6
#A   1   7
#A   1   8
#A   1   9
#A   1  10
```

Comment: I see, thought I saw someone using grepl() on a df before. Thanks!